# Python - поменять порядок букв в строке

Tags: python, python-3.x

Программа должна менять порядок букв в строке, но вместо этого она переделывает сам буквенный состав строки. Вот код:

```
from random import randint

mass = []
any_str = str(input("Input any string you want: "))

for i in  any_str:
 mass.append(i)

print("")
print(mass)

mass2 = []  

j = randint(0,len(mass))

for k in mass:
 mass2.append(mass[j])
 j = randint(0,len(mass))

print(mass2)
```

Comment: в сторону (не относится к вопросу): зачем str() вокруг input() поставили? Вы это где-то увидели?

Answer (score 8):

Проблема в том, что в `mass2` вы просто набиваете случайные символы из `mass1` без учёта повторов (не проверяете, что символы уже были использованы)

В модуле `random` есть функция `shuffle` как раз для перемешивания:

```
any_str = "123456"
mass2 = list(any_str)
random.shuffle(mass2)
print(mass2)
```

Также, там же есть функция `sample`:

```
print(random.sample(any_str, len(any_str)))
```

Comment: спасибо, а что такое print(' '.join(l)

Comment: Построение строки из списка (соединение с пустым разделителем)

Comment: Если нужен список, можете это убрать)

Answer (score 0):

если делать примерно как автор, то так

```
from random import randrange
mass1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
mass2 = [mass1.pop(randrange(len(mass1))) for _ in range(len(mass1))]
```

Comment: в отличии от `random.shuffle()`, `mass1.pop()` ведёт к квадратичному алгоритму (плохо для больших len(mass1))